# Is it possible to save an html element with child elements as JS variable which you can dynamically append to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form snippet

```
<div id="form-container" class="row">
       <select style="width:250px;" name="drug_pack_size" id="drug_pack_size" class="form-control">
         <option value="">Selling Unit</option>
         <option value="Ampoule">Ampoule</option>
       </select>
       <span class="d-flex">
         <p class="mx-3">contains</p>
         <input type="text" class="form-control">
       </span>
       <span class="d-flex">
         <p class="mx-3">for</p>
         <input type="text" class="form-control">
         <p class="mx-3">GHC</p>
       </span>
     </div>
```

Is it possible to do something like this

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form-element').content
```

Such that you can append it repeatedly and dynamically with JS code, without writing everything from the JS Backend

Comment: If you need whole form i think you need `innerHTML`

Comment: Yes, but you'll duplicate the IDs which will probably cause problems as they're supposed to be unique (on ID per element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Please try

```
 var x = document.getElementById("form-container").outerHTML;
 window.alert(x);
```

After this capture, if you want to repeatedly add same parent Element, then include variable(s) to increment the `id` and/or `name` of the parent and child elements to prevent duplication. For example, `id="form-container1"`, `id="form-container2"`, `id="form-container3"`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir/Madam